# Firebase Realtime Database: User ID not displaying within child

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I am setting up a Register/Login App using Firebase.  In my Real Time Database I have two Children, "Vendor" and "Eater" which are both under "Clients" parent.  When the user registers, it saves their info correctly to the Firebase Authentication Tab, but when I go to Realtime Database Tab, it doesn't show the user ID in any of the children.

I have already tried a DatabaseReference to store the userID to the correct child but it doesn't seem to be storing the userID to the Database, it only stores the user to the Authentication.

```
public class VendorLoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText emailEditText;
private EditText passwordEditText;
private Button loginButton;
private Button registrationButton;

private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener fbAuthenticationListener;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_vendor_login);

    emailEditText = findViewById(R.id.email_edit_text);
    passwordEditText = findViewById(R.id.password_edit_text);
    loginButton = findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    registrationButton = findViewById(R.id.registration_button);

    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    fbAuthenticationListener =  new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            FirebaseUser fbUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
            if (fbUser != null ){
                startActivity(new Intent(VendorLoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
                finish();
                return;
            }
        }
    };

    // Registration Button Clicked
    registrationButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final String emailUser = emailEditText.getText().toString();
            final String passwordUser = passwordEditText.getText().toString();
            firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(emailUser, passwordUser).addOnCompleteListener(VendorLoginActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                  if (!task.isSuccessful()){
                      Toast.makeText(VendorLoginActivity.this, R.string.registration_fail_toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  } else{
                      Toast.makeText(VendorLoginActivity.this, R.string.registration_success_toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                      String client_id = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
                      DatabaseReference client_db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Clients").child("Vendor").child(client_id);
                      client_db.setValue(true);
                  }
                }
            });
        }
    });

    // Login Button Clicked
    loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final String emailUser = emailEditText.getText().toString();
            final String passwordUser = passwordEditText.getText().toString();
            firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(emailUser, passwordUser).addOnCompleteListener(VendorLoginActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (!task.isSuccessful()){
                        Toast.makeText(VendorLoginActivity.this, R.string.login_failed_toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(VendorLoginActivity.this, R.string.login_success_toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    firebaseAuth.addAuthStateListener(fbAuthenticationListener);
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    firebaseAuth.removeAuthStateListener(fbAuthenticationListener);
}
}
```

I expect the userId to display in the Firebase Realtime Database child "Vendor" or "Eater" (depending on which button the user first pressed on the Welcome Screen) but instead the Firebase Realtime Database does not show any userId in any of the children "Vendor" or "Eater."

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem. If you run the code in a debugger, does the `client_db.setValue(true);` get executed?

Comment: Yes the client_db_setValue(true) does get executed.  In fact, it shows the user ID in the debug as well so its working fine.  When I go to the Firebase Website and the Authentication Tab shows the user I created with the registration, but when I go to the Firebase Database, it doesnt show the User ID that should be created under the correct child, it just shows empty.  Is it because in the Database Rules I have the read and write set to false? https://drive.google.com/file/d/1siaEJlrGqZKZ-xrRgW_ByaTQxDB4Sntt/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Yes, that would definitely explain. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/quickstart#sample-rules

Comment: Awesome thank you!  That leaves me to wonder though, since that is not how it should be during the final release, how would I go about being able to get the user ID while at the same making it releasable without any security issues since I wont be able to use the rules read and write set to true?  Thank you for your help and guidance!

Comment: Study the documentation on security rules, try to build your security rules, and if you get stuck, post back with a concrete question on that. See [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for hints on how to do that.

Comment: changing the rules also worked for me! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I just adjust my rules in Realtime Database and it's working.
Here are my codes:

```
{
    "rules": {
        ".read": false,
        ".write": true
    }
  }
```